# Hibernate session interaction with two different databases

Tags: java, hibernate, session

In hibernate, we have created one session.
Now I want my session to interact with two different databases. 
How it can be done?

I explained interviewer that we can define two configuration files for different dialects but he was not convinced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have two separate configuration files, and create two different SessionFactories with them, one for each.

This will allow you to create a session for each database. However, it is impossible to have one session access both databases.

Therefore, what you need to do is to create two sessions, and work with each individually. You may of course copy objects / fields from entities obtained from one database into new entities which are then persisted in the other database.